# sIFR 2 or sIFR 3 Beta or sIFR Lite! or Jquery sIFR plugin which one is better to use and why?

Tags: jquery-plugins, sifr

sIFR 2 or sIFR 3 Beta which one is better to use and why ? What are the basic differences ? Which one will give better error free rendering solution?

And is it better to make font with FLASH IDE or no problem with online converter?

1. sIFR2 - http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/
2. sIFR3 Beta - http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/
3. sIFR Lite - http://www.allcrunchy.com/Web_Stuff/sIFR_lite/
4. Jquery sIFR Plugin - http://jquery.thewikies.com/sifr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use sIFR 3, and have never had reason to look back.

1: sIFR 2 lacks a bunch of features which you may not need now, but may need in the future.

3: sIFR Lite is significantly less mature (less adoptation, less available support) than vanilla sIFR.

4:  The plugin, as far as I know, still requires some version of sIFR, so you'll still have to choose between option 1 and option 2 here.

Comment: If i'm already using Jquery on my site then what will be good option standalonesifr or jquery plugin

Comment: I know stand-alone sIFR isn't too hard to get working, and it will probably be easier to get support for if problems arise, at the cost of a bit more work setting it up.

That being said, I haven't actually used jQuery sIFR...

Answer (score 2):

jQuery sIFR isn't an exact port, so you're going to be better of using sIFR 3 r436.